# Flutter : How to get Linear Gauge for weight and height (Without SyncFusion plugin or any licensed plugin)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement line scale for weight and height for my app, I have tried using custom paint but i dont know how to use the custom paint their are no specific tutorials or guide for it. But now, i am trying to implement this scale as below image

PS. I need thoes values in input field

[image]

And i need to get this scale work logically as eplained below

how to get after selecting 55 kg and display same 121.245 lb vice versa so both values should be equal for example `55 kg = 121.254 lb`